# Break display into multiple line for anchor tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My need is to display text into multiple lines i use bootstrap and it divided into 2 lines when width is completed but can is it possible to break the line when i need to break.?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Non-Owned & Hired Auto", "", "", new { id=1}, new { })
```

In the above code auto line break after Hired word but i want to break line after this and sign (&). Please guide me how to do this.

I am using Asp.net Mvc with Razor View Engine.

Following is the html view code.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <aside id="sidebar">
        <nav id="side-nav">
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                  <li id="basicDetailMenu">@Html.ActionLink("Basic", "", "", new { id = 1}, new { })</li>
                                  <li id="generalInfoMenu">@Html.ActionLink("General", "", "", new { id=1}, new { })</li>
                  <li id="priorCarrierMenu">@Html.ActionLink("Prior Carrier", "", "", new { id=1}, new { })</li>
                  <li id="propertyCoverageMenu">@Html.ActionLink("Property Coverage", "", "", new { id=1}, new { })</li>
                          <li id="liabilityCoverageMenu">@Html.ActionLink("Liability Coverage", "", "", new { id=1}, new { })</li>
                  <li id="nonOwnedMenu">@Html.ActionLink("Non-Owned & Hired Auto", "", "", new { id=1}, new { })</li>
                                  <li id="liquorLiabilityMenu">@Html.ActionLink("Liquor Liability Coverage", "", "", new { id=1}, new { })</li>
                  <li><a href="#tab5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Additional</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#tab6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Other</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
</div>
```

And here is the css

```
#sidebar{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 15px;
}
#side-nav{
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
}
#side-nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#side-nav ul li{
    font-size:14px;
    border-top:1px solid #465667;
}
#side-nav ul li a{
    color:#9eabba;
    padding:15px;
    display:block;
    background:#293440;
    transition:.5s all;
    height:50px;
    line-height:18px;
}
#side-nav ul li a span{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Please share your html structure also and if you have tried any CSS, share it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a carriage return to the text (note class name added for styling)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Non-Owned & \rHired Auto", "", "", new { id = 1 }, new { @class = "newlinelink" })
```

and then use css to style it

```
.newlinelink {
    white-space:pre;
}
```